# When performing matrix multiplications in neural networks, is it acceptable to do X * W rather than W * X?

Tags: neural-networks, matrix, weights

I'm having a hard time seeing a clear convention being used and I've seen it both ways. X * W would assume the features (X) are in row format, and the weights are in column format.

Is there anything wrong with that?

This is mostly for pedagogy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not wrong of course. You just need to be consistent with your definition across your application, e.g. while differentiating in the back-propagation phase etc.

Comment: Does one approach tend to be more popular than the other?

Comment: As far as I see, W * x is more popular, i.e. each line is a neuron's weights.